# Can we store hashmap in mongoDB using loopback

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, loopbackjs

I'm using MongoDB with Loopback as backend stack for my application. I want to store a hashmap in MongoDB model/table. If I use an array it uses custom indexes (i.e 0,1,2...). I want these indexes to be hash key. Following is my desired structure in DB, and it needs to be implemented through loopback 3.xx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riwVH.png)

The issue is that loopback does not support hashmap property type.
Does anybody know a workaround?? would be a great help

Comment: Is mechanicResponded an embeded relation or an hashmap property? If it's a relation, maybe you could use a mix of [embeds many](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#embedsmany) and [custom ID](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#id-properties)?

Comment: @akkonrad mechanicResponded is not a relation, it's a key of order object. it will hold a hashmap as a value.

Comment: so then you can use the [embeds many](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#embedsmany) only, that should solve your issue.